# Kinematics LHS≠RHS?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

For example, $v_f=v_i+a\Delta t=1+1(1),v_f=2$

Then after finding final velocity i try to find $\Delta x$:

$\Delta x=\frac 12(v_i+v_f), \frac 12(1+2)1=1.5m$

However $\Delta x=v_f-v_i$=2-1=1m

1m≠1.5m

Edit:try to forget that this question exists.

Comment: Where to you get $\Delta x=v_{f}-v_{i}$? The units aren't even right.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Comment: for a moment i forgot and thought it was v$_f-v_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general formula for displacement is

$$s=v_{i}t+\frac{at^2}{2}$$

Therefore, for your example $\Delta x$ = (1)(1) + $\frac{(1)(1)^{2}}{2}$ = 1.5 m.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your right, for a moment i forgot and thought it was $v_f-v_i$.